# Lucene query finds [0 TO 1] for value e.g. 167

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I've opened the Index with Luke and the field is there.

The field is indexed via HibernateSearch and is annotated like this:

```
@Field(name = "id", index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO)
Long id
```

The values of this field are between 109 and 185.
If I search for this field e.g:
[150 TO 180]
then nothing is found.

If I search for it with:
[0 TO 1]
then all results are returned.
It seems the field is indexed in a wrong format, correct?
How to correct this?

Note that I also indexed it one time with store = Store.YES to see in Luke the values and could see them correctly.

Comment: Please show the code used to create the query.

Comment: It‘s groovy code and I don‘t think its necessary, because I‘m talking here about the search string I‘m pasting into Luke.

Answer (score 0):

The query parsers in Lucene will treat everything as strings. It makes sense: At query time Lucene has no idea of which types has been used. This means they will create string range queries.

So if you want Lucene to create a proper numeric range query you'll need to subclass `MultiFieldsQueryParser` (assuming you use that) and override `newRangeQuery`. There you can check the field name and create a range query (e.g. with `LongPoint.newRangeQuery()`) if it's a field you know it's numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I now found out that I've to use
`NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange()`